# Disabling unecessary low-speed charging audio alert

Tags: charging, audio

Phone: Moto e5 Play
Android version: 8.0.0
Build Number: ODP27.91-167-9-19
Kernel Version: 3.18.71.perf-g3501b0bbb34d (May 30, 2020)
Configuration version: F16.MOT.moto e5 play.0

My phone has always had one incredibly annoying feature. When it detects a low-charge speed mode, it emits a chime. The low-charge-speed mode, the warning claims, can be due to not using the USB cable provided with the phone. I've never used anything but the OEM cable that came with the phone. The alert is not predictable. I'll go months not hearing it... then spend the next five nights being awakened in the middle of the night by the chime, which fires over and over and over, often dozens of times.

From the perspective of how I use the phone, the warning is entirely useless. I plug the phone in each night to recharge. That it takes a couple of hours rather than 40 minutes means nothing to me.

I've searched my settings, but can't find a way to disable this warning. It wouldn't be a big deal if it didn't have an audio chime — as if the world will come to an end if I don't do something to return rapid charging *right now!*

Is there a way to disable this warning?

*I apologize that I don't have a screenshot of this warning. I can't make it happen and it's unpredictable.*